# mem_limit not being honored with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to define a container in my docker-compose.yml file like so -

```
gitea:
  image: gitea/gitea:latest
  depends_on: 
    - mariadb
  env_file: 
    - gitea_env
  mem_limit: 100000000
  ports:
    - "127.0.0.1:4567:3000"
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/gitea:/data
```

However, once the container starts, I see with `docker stats` that the memory assigned to it is not limited to 100 MB. I am using `version: '2'` of docker-compose YML syntax and docker-compose version is 1.25.5.

Output of `docker stats --all gitea` shows -

```
CONTAINER ID        NAME                CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT   MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
dfed6585837c        gitea               0.25%               150MiB / 982.8MiB   15.27%              251kB / 102kB       57.2MB / 69.6kB     12
```

Docker version (`docker --version`) is -
`Docker version 19.03.8-ce, build afacb8b7f0`

What is going wrong in my configuration?

Comment: did you try mem_limit: 100m ?

Comment: Yep, tried that too, and it doesn't work either

Comment: Can you share the output of "docker stat --all" ?

Comment: Updated in the question!

Comment: Sorry for the edit in my previous comment, please mention docker engine version too.

Comment: Yes, added that as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218118/discussion-between-gaurav-agarwal-and-upincloud).

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you are not running different compose file (it happens)? I have just tested it on version 2 and exact docker version/build and it works correctly.

Comment: Do you have the kernel options given in the grub file? I haven't given those!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are recreating the container after changing the memory limit:

```
docker-compose down && docker-compose up
```

Comment: Holy! That was the reason! I was maybe just stopping and starting the same container with `docker-compose stop gitea` and `docker-compose start gitea`